# Change language in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, multilingual, laravel-blade

I just begin to use Laravel 5.4, In the login.blade.php i have

[image]

I don't like to put plain text in html code, is there a solution to make all the texts in seperate lang files to use them dynamically?

Thank you

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `resources/lang` folder contains localization files. The file name corresponds to the view that it will be used. In order to get a value from this file, you can simply use the following code:

`Lang::geConfig;
use Session;

```
    class Locale
    {
      /**
       * Handle an incoming request.
       *
       * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
       * @param  \Closure  $next
       * @return mixed
       */
       public function handle($request, Closure $next)
       {
         //$raw_locale = Session::get('locale');
         $raw_locale = $request->session()->get('locale');
         if (in_array($raw_locale, Config::get('app.locales'))) {
           $locale = $raw_locale;
         }
         else $locale = Config::get('app.locale');
           App::setLocale($locale);
           return $next($request);
       }
     }
```

3. In `app/Http/Kernel.php` in `$middlewareGroups=[ ... ]` add the following line:

   `\App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class,`
4. In `routes/web.php` add:

   ```
   Route::get('setlocale/{locale}', function ($locale) {
     if (in_array($locale, \Config::get('app.locales'))) {
       session(['locale' => $locale]);
     }
     return redirect()->back();
   });
   ```

Comment: the most straightforward solution!

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, it's working well on Lar 5.7

Comment: Amazing solution!

Comment: I got an error
`in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`

In this file "C:\wamp64\www\larav_start_youtube_2\app\Http\Middleware\Locale.php"
In this line 
 `$raw_locale = Session::get('locale');
     if (in_array($raw_locale, Config::get('app.locales'))) {
       $locale = $raw_locale; `

Comment: I did not find this routes/web.php file anywhere. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 4):

Try this!

```
{{ @lang('messages.login') }}
```

Now Add login key with it's value under language file as below

`return['login'=>'Login']; // write inside messages file`

and Set your APP Config Local Variable Like `'en','nl','us'`

`App::setLocale(language name); like 'en','nl','us'`

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a [localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization) module.

Basically, you create a file, ex: `resources/lang/en/login.php` and put

```
return [
    'header' => 'Login'
];
```

And in your template you use `@lang('login.header')` instead of `Login`.

You can have as many files in your `/resources/lang/en` directory and using `@lang` blade directive you put your file name (without extension) and desired value separated with dot.