# Laravel - How to make a button that set my locale during a whole session until the session ends or other button to change the locale?

Tags: php, laravel, button, locale

I already have the php files with the tradutions inside for pt-br and es. Now I have to create 2 buttons to switch the locale to es and pt. I'm using php/laravel.

Comment: the very perfect answer was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395481/change-language-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

Set the locale using these lines.

```
Route::get('switch/{locale}', function ($locale) { 
    App::setLocale($locale); 
});
```

Comment: when I use this. Appear an error sayng Undefined class App.

Comment: Use \App::setLocale($locale);

Comment: this way, the user will be redirected to site.com/switch/pt  and appears page not found. What can I do to the user stay on his current page?

Comment: Perform return redirect()->back(); to return to previous page.

Comment: it's not working, my guess is: when return some route or function like back(), the config fallback => 'en' is activated.

Comment: what if I perform the setLocale function to all my routes? Is it so wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set locale by url, you may want to add these lines in `RouteServiceProvider.php`.

```
public function boot()
{
    I18n::bootI18nService();

    parent::boot();
}
```

and in `I18n::bootI18nService()`, do something like

```
    $language = Request::segment(1);
    App::setLocale($language);
```

At the beginning of your routes/web.php, add

```
Route::prefix(App::getLocale())->group(function (){

  // your routes
})
```

Then if you visit yoursite.com/en/blabla, your site will show english translation.

That is just a rough workaround, real code should be much more robust.

Comment: thanks for helping me. I didn't use your solution because I found this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395481/change-language-in-laravel-5