# Laravel route group optional prefix not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes, router

I have some routes grouped by a prefix as below. But it's not working without {lang} in URL. URLs without {lang} will get a 404 error. Can anyone guess what the problem is?

**Routes**

```php
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Site', 'prefix' => '{lang?}', 
    'where' => array('lang' => 'en|fa')], function () {

    if (\Request::segment(1) !== 'panel' || \Request::segment(1) !== 'login') {
        $locale = \Request::segment(1);
        if (in_array($locale, ['fa', 'en'])) Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::setLocale($locale);
    }

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/about', 'AboutController@index')->name('about');
    Route::get('/portfolio', 'PortfolioController@index');
    Route::get('/portfolio/{category_id}/cat', 'PortfolioController@indexWithCategory');
    Route::get('/portfolio/loadmore/{category_id}/cat', 'PortfolioController@loadmore');
    Route::get('/portfolio/loadmore', 'PortfolioController@loadmore');
    Route::get('/portfolio/{id}/{title}', 'PortfolioController@show');
    Route::get('/articles', 'ArticleController@index');
    Route::get('/articles/{id}/', 'ArticleController@article_show');
    Route::get('/articles/{id}/{title}', 'ArticleController@article_show');
    Route::get('/blogs', 'ArticleController@blogs');
    Route::get('/blogs/{id}', 'ArticleController@show');
    Route::get('/blogs/{id}/{title}', 'ArticleController@show');
    Route::get('/faq', 'ArticleController@faq');
    Route::get('/contacts', 'ContactsController@index');
});
```

Comment: PS. HomeController works!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the optional lang prefix.

Just separate the routes in two categories: 
1. which will have lang prefix

2. which does not have lang prefix

OR, it would be better if you use lang at the end of the route instead of using it as a prefix.

Comment: Problem with separating is controllers need to get lang parameter so I should separate controllers too

Answer (score -1):

dont use optional parameter for prefix, prefix is about using a fix parameter in begining of urls, so now laravel routing dont know what is your fix segment  exactly!! with this route group you can send any parameter or string as prefix for exmple  this routes foo/about, bar/about , xxxx/about all of them go to the about url

Comment: Thanks for explaining so what is the best way to define an optional prefix for lang?

Comment: read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395481/change-language-in-laravel-5