# Laravel localization not working in all routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I Blog in Laravel v5.6
when translate new route it doesn't work for me
but old route like login and register and landing pages it working as well when i going in new route it's not

### Switch Lang page

```
    Route::get('locale/{locale}', function ($locale) {

        Session::put('locale', $locale);
        return redirect()->back();

        // this link will add session of language when they click to change langauge

    })->name('locale');
```

```
Route::get('/{username}', 'ProfileAccountController@index')->name('profile')->middleware('admin.user');
```

when i going to this route it's not working and navbar and footer it's back to key, remove all code in this page and test the lang it's not work too.

I use all of this command and nothing

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should assign locale in an early point of your application, maybe in a middleware or in a ServiceProvider.  if(session()->get('locale'))       app()->setLocale(session()->get('locale'))

Comment: when i remove middleware it work as well

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:
Use middle-wear for changing languages and use https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable like this for more comfortable usage. 
Also check this [Change language in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395481/change-language-in-laravel-5) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issues with Route closures. Try moving you're session setters/getters to a Controller and not within a Route closure.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#using-the-session

This will probably solve your issues.